# How to dynamically weight a random generator to guide a result set toward a desired distribution?

Tags: algorithms

Say I have a function that returns a weighted selection from a set of resources, according to a desired distribution.  For argument's sake let that resource be string colors.

```
const distribution = {
  red: .1666,    // We want 1/6th of colors in the world to be 'red'  
  yellow: .3333, // ... 1/3 to be 'yellow'
  blue: .5       // ... and 1/2 to be 'blue'
}

// returns ~1/6 'red', ~1/3 'yellow', ~1/2 'blue'
function getWeightedColor() {...}
```

If I wanted to further weight the return value based on existing data with the purpose of guiding the data toward the desired distribution more quickly, how would I achieve that?

```
// Accepts a counts dict in the format `{<color>: count, ...}` and based on
// the distribution of that dict, further weights the selection such that
// the return value adjusts the dict toward the desired distribution.
function getWeightedColor(colorCounts) {...}

// Examples:

getWeightedColor({red: 100, yellow: 200, blue: 300}); 
// given distribution already normal, so we'd use the unadjusted weights

getWeightedColor({red: 100, yellow: 250, blue: 10});
// given distribution has far too few blues and somewhat too many yellows, 
// so the weights would be adjusted to compensate. The odds of 'blue'
// would be greatly increased, red somewhat decreased and yellow moreso.
```

Comment: "with the purpose of guiding the data back toward the desired distribution" you're going to have to first define how you want the historical data to influence the weighting. That decision is not trivial.

Comment: No historical influence, just adjusted weights driving the random generation to push the counts back toward the equilibrium distribution.  An extreme example would be that somehow a data group had 1000 members and 0 blue, when the desired ratio of blue is 0.5.  The weighting would be adjusted such that the function returned *almost 100% blue*, then gradually less and less as the ratio of blues neared 0.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unevenly distributed random number generation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255892/unevenly-distributed-random-number-generation)

Comment: @numbers1311407: No historical influence? You clearly are not aware of what you don't know. You need to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy and think hard about the conflict in what you just wrote.

Comment: @gnat this question looks like that one but is definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: @whatsisname I think you may be misunderstanding the question.  Maybe you're assuming the data passed to the function is always created by the function and unmodified?  As I tried to convey in the last comment the point is to adjust the odds based on how far the data is from the expected distribution, *to the extreme point where the result is hardly random*.  It's not gamber's fallacy to bet on heads if the coin has one side.  If there's something fundamentally wrong with the question I'm not seeing (this may very well be true), please explain as an answer.

Comment: @numbers1311407 The point is that you are saying that you are passing in historical data and want that to help you more rapidly adjust the probabilities until you hit some ideal distribution.  Then you say that the same historical data should not influence anything.   You can't have it both ways.  For example, in your example, you give a sample where there are 360 total items and the blues seem to be "too low" (where does that threshold lie?).  Just because the blues seem out of whack now doesn't mean that when you get to a sample size of 10,000 that it won't have naturally evened out.  (cont)

Comment: @numbers1311407 (cont) Why do you want to get back to some "ideal distribution"?  Is there a time frame constraint (ie. I need there to be a randomized "winner" every hour and there hasn't been one in the last 58 minutes)?  Where does this historical data come from and why is it important to hit this "ideal distribution"?  How much data can influence this?  The data from the last hour?  The last day?  All data?  If you pick a small enough sample size, you can always find something that doesn't hit the magic ideal. (cont)

Comment: @numbers1311407 (cont) But with a sufficiently large sample size, you will hit that ideal (or close enough).  The only reason to do this would be because some small sample doesn't line up with what a larger data set would achieve.  Why are you looking at a small sample and why is it important to move it back toward some ideal, such that a given small sample achieves the same distribution as a larger set? (Sorry this was so long.)

Comment: @Becuzz I thought this might be the misunderstanding and tried explain it in the follow up comment, but I realize I wasn't clear.  The data passed into the function can be modified outside the function and **is not historical**.  The goal is that I want to maintain an approximate distribution of each item in "the world". The question is how to dynamically adjust the weighting used by the function in reaction to the state of "the world" to more quickly bring that state closer to the desired distribution. Pieter B has the right idea in his answer, but I'm looking for more.

Comment: A distribution so adjusted is no longer random, is it?  Unless perhaps you consider [this](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png) random.

Comment: The distribution is decidedly not random.  That's the question basically, how to reduce randomness to help guide the state towards the desired distribution, but I see how the wording of the question and assumptions around the goal make that confusing.

Comment: @numbers1311407: I know what you are asking. What you need to realize, is that **you** actually don't. The gamblers fallacy is about how each independent event has unchanging odds, regardless what took place before it. After 20 heads in a row, the odds of the next coin flip is still 50/50. You want to have a system where the gamblers fallacy becomes true. In order to do that, you have to look at the previous flips to change your odds for the next one. Those previous flips are "historical data". You also need to realize the difference between "difference" and "proportion" to your results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random numbers with a (negative) sloping distribution?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200360/how-to-generate-random-numbers-with-a-negative-sloping-distribution)

Comment: @gnat should have VTC'd as the question that the one you voted for is a duplicate of. It even has a really nice answer written up by the late, great MichaelT that explains what OP needs perfectly.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This feels like an XY problem..

Comment: Related reading: **[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/)**

Comment: It may very well be an XY problem.  I'll try to rewrite the question when I can.

Answer (score 2):

> If I wanted to further weight the return value based on existing data
>   with the purpose of guiding the data toward the desired distribution
>   more quickly, how would I achieve that?

This is the crux of the question, and what makes it different from the proposed duplicates. You want a weighted distribution, but one which skews toward the desired ratio *while the algorithm is running*.

The easiest way to do this is to treat this like a deck of cards where each card is one outcome possible in your algorithm (e.g. color, in your example). The algorithm looks like this:

1. Construct a deck of N cards where N is the least common multiple of the denominator in each of the odds. In your example, LCM(2,3,6) = 6.
2. Add cards for each possibility so the overall ratio is correct. In your example, you would add one red, two yellow, and three blue. 1/6 red, 2/6 = 1/3 yellow, and 3/6 = 1/2 blue.
3. Shuffle the deck.
4. Each time a color is requested, pull the next card off the top of the deck.
5. If the previous step fails because there are no more cards, return to step 1 and continue to the previous step.

This differs from a typical algorithm for selecting weighted values because each draw is dependent on the previous one. Consider a game of [Monopoly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_(game)). Each time a player rolls the dice, any of the eleven possibilities (2-12) can occur with varying odds and this is true no matter when the player rolls. Compare to landing on Chance or Community Chest. The odds of drawing a specific card vary over the course of the game as the decks are depleted and eventually reshuffled. If there is a single card left to draw, and the player has been keeping track (or looks in the discard pile), it is possible to know exactly what the card is before drawing it. The first example is an *independent* event, the second example is a *dependent* event because drawing card N relies on all draws from 1 to N-1. The *order* is random, but the overall odds are precisely 1/6, 1/3, and 1/2 given a multiple of six draws.

Answer (score 1):

If you just keep running the function long enough it will naturally converge to the weights you specified.

But that's not fast enough.

What you want is dynamic weights.
The problem with that is, that there is no one right way to do it and it would determinately make your algorithm "less random" it would to some height become predictable.

For instance your distribution could become:

```
red
1/6 + 1/6*(1/6 - redamound/totalamount)
yellow
1/3 + 1/3*(1/3 - yellowamount/totalamount)
blue:
1/2 + 1/2*(1/2 - blueamount/totalamount)
```

This will push your distribution towards your desired distribution faster if it further from it.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I'm looking for.  **Predictability is fine here**.  I think that point may have confused the question.  Do you know of any resources where I can research similar techniques as the one you describe?